# Suggestion for test case managment tool

Tags: testing, manual-testing

First off, please forgive me if this has been answered before. I did do a search before posting but the results that came back were not really satisfying. This is question is a "last resort" type of thing, to point us to the right direction, if at all possible.

My team and I have been looking for a good test case management tool. So far we have been using Zephyr, but we find it to be quite bloated and a tad complicated for what we believe we need.

What we need the tool with the following features.

1. Integration with Jira
2. Good reporting capabilities (much like Zephyr).
3. **Support for agile teams.**
4. Support for multiple projects over multiple iterations.
5. Nice, clean and intuitive interface

**Some things to consider:**

We have rejected Jira as a test management tool because we feel handling multiple projects with it would be a real pain

We have also rejected Zephyr for Jira, pretty much for the same reasons, and because of our current experience with Zephyr.

Would it possible for you to recommend any tool that satisfies the above features?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you take a look at [PractiTest](http://www.practitest.com)?

I am biased because I work for them, but on the other hand the system provides all the things you mentioned above that you are looking for (simple to use, good integration with Jira, supports Agile teams, etc) and some additional features and things that make the life of the average tester easier and overall better.

You can sign up to one of the public demos that run once or twice a week from the site.  And after the demo you can choose to work with PractiTest for free for a couple of weeks as part of the 2-week free evaluation license.

As you said, testing and test management should not be complex and over-bloated...

-joel

Comment: Thanks Joel! I'll definitely take a look! I'll leave the question floating for a couple more days, in case more people want to contribute :)

Comment: Thanks again Joel. My team is currently considering PractiTest, among other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try APTEST (product of Atlassian). With APTEST integration with JIRA is made simpler. It connect tests and test results to issues in JIRA. For more details check the following link [APTEST - JIRA Integration](http://www.aptest.com/atm2/integration/atlassian.html)